# Mongoose not saving embedded object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following Schema defined:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var VenueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String,
    address: {address1: String, address2: String, suburb: String, state: String, postCode: Number, country: {type: String, default: 'Australia'}},
    ABN: String,
    website: String,
    openingHours: [{order: Number, day: Date, open: String, close: String}],
    closedDays: [{startDate: Date, endDate: Date}],
    supportEmail: String
});

var Venue = mongoose.model('Venue', VenueSchema);

module.exports = Venue;
```

And I have the following method defined in Express to save the document:

```
app.post('/api/venues/:id', function (req, res) {
        Venue.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {upsert: true, new: true}, function (err, venue) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            else {
                res.status(200).json(venue);
            }                
        });
    });
```

The problem is, when the document contains an `openingHours` array, the resulting saved document looks like this in the `mongo` console:

```
"openingHours" : [
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("563be68ce65bf8543c6ec5e0")
        }
],
```

I can confirm, the object is being passed to the Express method, as `req.body.openingHours` has the correct length and object within. And obviously something is happening, otherwise `Mongo` would not have the `_id` file populated, however, I don't understand why that is even happening. I have not defined a separate schema for this, it is simply an array of objects embedded within the doc.

There must be something simple which I am missing?

**UPDATE**
If I change the code withing my `Express` method to the following:

```
Venue.update({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {multi: true}, function (err, raw) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            else {
                Venue.findById(req.params.id, function(err, venue) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500).send(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        res.status(200).json(venue);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Then my `mongo` console looks like this:

```
"openingHours" : [
        {
                "order" : 0,
                "day" : "Monday",
                "open" : "10:00",
                "close" : "22:00",
                "_id" : ObjectId("563bf15ac16e007832e025ae")
        },
        {
                "order" : 1,
                "day" : "Tuesday",
                "open" : "10:00",
                "close" : "22:00",
                "_id" : ObjectId("563bf197c16e007832e025af")
        },
        {
                "order" : 2,
                "day" : "Wednesday",
                "open" : "10:00",
                "close" : "22:00",
                "_id" : ObjectId("563bf19bc16e007832e025b0")
        }
],
```

Now I dont understand 2 things:
1. Why does `mongo` treat objects embedded in arrays differently to plain old embedded objeects? i.e. the embedded `address` object does not have an `_id` field assigned to it when you save or update.
2. Why does `findOneAndUpdate` behave so differently? Is it because of `{multi: true}`?

Comment: hi @Sandor A, did you find any solution for this? me too struggling with the same issue.